# How do you override Typesafe Config settings?

Tags: sbt, typesafe, typesafe-config

In my application.conf file I have something like

```
platform3.operational.state = "development"
```

I run my service with

```
sbt "project p3-s-sink" "run -Dplatform3.operational.state=test"
```

But the configuration property is still "development"

How do you override typesafe-config settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this blog helps you:

> Unfortunately sbt run doesn’t support java system properties so you can’t tweak settings with the command line when running sbt. The sbt-revolver plugin, which allows you to run your app in a forked JVM, does allow you to pass java arguments using the command line.

http://blog.michaelhamrah.com/2014/02/leveraging-typesafes-config-library-across-environments/

Answer (score 1):

From JavaDoc of ConfigFactory.systemProperties() [[ConfigFactory.java](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/config/src/main/java/com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory.java)]:

> ```
>  * Gets a <code>Config</code> containing the system properties from
>  * {@link java.lang.System#getProperties()}, parsed and converted as with
>  * {@link #parseProperties}.
>  * <p>
>  * This method can return a global immutable singleton, so it's preferred
>  * over parsing system properties yourself.
>  * <p>
>  * {@link #load} will include the system properties as overrides already, as
>  * will {@link #defaultReference} and {@link #defaultOverrides}.
>  *
>  * <p>
>  * Because this returns a singleton, it will not notice changes to system
>  * properties made after the first time this method is called. Use
>  * {@link #invalidateCaches()} to force the singleton to reload if you
>  * modify system properties.
>  *
>  * @return system properties parsed into a <code>Config</code>
> ```

Note the middle paragraph: "load will include the system properties as override already, as will defaultReference and defaultOverrides".

Does it work as expected when you execute directly?

Comment: Yes it does when I run it directly.